# Server doesn't remove client from list

Tags: c#, sockets, client-server, listener

I have a client-server applications.
The server can handle multiple client connections.

When I click the `Close` button in the client, I expect it to be disconnected, and removed from the list of clients in the server form.

However, it enters an infinite loop, which causes the client to be removed from the form's `ListView`, and then added again to the form's `ListView`.

Here is my code:

**RemoteBatcherClientForm**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace RemoteBatcherClient
{
    public partial class RemoteBatcherClientForm : Form
    {
        Socket clientSock;

        public RemoteBatcherClientForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            clientSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        }

        private void connectBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            clientSock.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8);
            MessageBox.Show("Connected");
        }

        private void sendBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (clientSock.Send(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(txtMsg.Text)) > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Data Sent");
            }
        }

        private void closeBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            clientSock.Close();
            clientSock.Dispose();
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**RemoteBatcherServer**:

Client.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace RemoteBatcherServer
{
    class Client
    {
        public string ID
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public IPEndPoint EndPoint
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        Socket serverSock;

        public Client(Socket accepted)
        {
            serverSock = accepted;

            ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            EndPoint = (IPEndPoint)serverSock.RemoteEndPoint;
            serverSock.BeginReceive(new byte[] { 0 }, 0, 0, 0, callback, null);
        }

        void callback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                serverSock.EndReceive(ar);

                byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[8192];

                int rec = serverSock.Receive(receiveBuffer, receiveBuffer.Length, 0);

                if (rec < receiveBuffer.Length)
                {
                    Array.Resize<byte>(ref receiveBuffer, rec);
                }

                 if (Receieved != null)
                {
                    Receieved(this, receiveBuffer);
                }

                serverSock.BeginReceive(new byte [] {0}, 0, 0, 0, callback, null);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Close();

                if (Disconnected != null)
                {
                    Disconnected(this);
                }
            }
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            serverSock.Close();
            serverSock.Dispose();
        }

        public delegate void ClientReceievedHandler(Client sender, byte[] data);
        public delegate void ClientDisconnectedHandler(Client sender);

        public event ClientReceievedHandler Receieved;
        public event ClientDisconnectedHandler Disconnected;
    }
}
```

Listener.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace RemoteBatcherServer
{
    class Listener
    {
        Socket sck;

        public bool Listening
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public int Port
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public Listener(int port)
        {
            Port = port;
            sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            if (Listening)
                return;

            sck.Bind(new IPEndPoint(0, Port));
            sck.Listen(0);

            sck.BeginAccept(callback, null);

            Listening = true;
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            if (!Listening)
                return;

            sck.Close();
            sck.Dispose();
            sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        }

        void callback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket acceptSocket = sck.EndAccept(ar);

                if (SockeetAccepted != null)
                {
                    SockeetAccepted(acceptSocket);
                }

                sck.BeginAccept(callback, null);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public delegate void SocketAcceptHandler(Socket acceptSocket);
        public event SocketAcceptHandler SockeetAccepted;
    }
}
```

RemoteBatcherServerForm.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace RemoteBatcherServer
{
    public partial class RemoteBatcherServerForm : Form
    {
        Listener listener;

        public RemoteBatcherServerForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listener = new Listener(8);
            listener.SockeetAccepted += new Listener.SocketAcceptHandler(listenerSocketAccepted);

            Load += new EventHandler(MainLoad);
        }

        void MainLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listener.Start();
        }

        void listenerSocketAccepted(Socket socket)
        {
            Client client = new Client(socket);
            client.Receieved += new Client.ClientReceievedHandler(clientReceived);
            client.Disconnected += new Client.ClientDisconnectedHandler(clientDisconnected);

            Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
                item.Text = client.EndPoint.ToString();
                item.SubItems.Add(client.ID);
                item.SubItems.Add("XX");
                item.SubItems.Add("XX");
                item.Tag = client;
                lstClients.Items.Add(item);
            });
        }

        void clientReceived(Client sender, byte[] data)
        {
            Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < lstClients.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    Client client = lstClients.Items[i].Tag as Client;

                    if (client.ID == sender.ID)
                    {
                        lstClients.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text = Encoding.Default.GetString(data);
                        lstClients.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        void clientDisconnected(Client sender)
        {
            Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < lstClients.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    Client client = lstClients.Items[i].Tag as Client;

                    if (client.ID == sender.ID)
                    {
                        lstClients.Items.RemoveAt(i);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });
        }       
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Not going to help you but you have a typo in `Listener.cs` - `SockeetAccepted` should be `SocketAccepted`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick answer: modify the `Client.cs`'s `void callback(IAsyncResult ar)` method in order to check if the [Socket.Available Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.available.aspx) returns 0 (this happens when the client is closed):

```
void callback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        //add these lines
        if (serverSock.Available == 0)
        {
            Disconnected(this);
            return;
        }

        serverSock.EndReceive(ar);

        byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[8192];

        int rec = serverSock.Receive(receiveBuffer, receiveBuffer.Length, 0);

        if (rec < receiveBuffer.Length)
        {
            Array.Resize<byte>(ref receiveBuffer, rec);
        }

        if (Receieved != null)
        {
            Receieved(this, receiveBuffer);
        }

        serverSock.BeginReceive(new byte[] { 0 }, 0, 0, 0, callback, null);
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        Close();

        if (Disconnected != null)
        {
            Disconnected(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing synchronous and asynchronous calls unless I'm misunderstanding your code. I think you're blocking indefinitely with your serverSock.Receive call. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s4y8aff.aspx - *"If no data is available for reading, the Receive method will block until data is available, unless a time-out value was set by using Socket.ReceiveTimeout"*

```
serverSock.EndReceive(ar);
byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[8192];
int rec = serverSock.Receive(receiveBuffer, receiveBuffer.Length, 0);
```

Try checking if you've received 0 bytes. You also probably want to swap out the receive call for a BeginReceive. It probably seems a bit confusing because you effectively want to keep re-calling BeginReceive until you receive 0 bytes, indicating the other side has closed the connection:

```
int i = serverSock.EndReceive(ar);
if (i > 0)
    {
        serverSock.BeginReceive(receiveBuffer, 0, receiveBuffer.Length, 0, 
                                 new AsyncCallback(callback), null);
    }
else
    {
        serverSock.Close();
    }
```

Note you can swap the null parameter for a state object you pass around. You can do this in your initial BeginReceive call in your Client constructor - this may be a better way of passing your buffer around, wrapping it with some kind of State class.